# webpack can't use jQuery by ProvidePlugin

Tags: jquery, webpack

My webpack config file adds following code:

```
plugins: [
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       jQuery: 'jquery',
       $: 'jquery'
     }),
     ...
```

I could use `$()` function but can't use `jQuery()` function on my project.

Has anyone ever faced such problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `window.jQuery`

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   $: 'jquery',
   jQuery: 'jquery',
   'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
})
```